# Cross chain interoperability

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, corda, atomic-swap

I'm looking into chain interoperability on network level (ex Fabric - Corda, Sawtooth - Ethereum, Corda entr - Corda os) and was wondering if there is any more (technical) information/research/demo available regarding this topic. I've done the EdX HL course online and had a look at Quilt & ILP already.

Kind regards,

Chaim

Comment: Corda Enterprise and Corda OS are completely interoperable and can run on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain implementations from separate organizations are usually not interoperable. There is a project called "Hyperledger Quilt" that ties together blockchain technologies.

Hyperledger Burrow implements the Ethereum EVM, so runs Ethereum Dapps written in Solidity.

Hyperledger Sawtooth has a Transaction Processor called "Seth" (for Sawtooth Ethereum) that uses Hyperledger Burrow to implement a Ethereum EVM.

Hyperledger Calipter does performance measurement and supports multiple blockchain technologies--including Sawtooth, Fabric, Iroha, and Ethereum EVM.